# extract a segment from some mp3 file

Tags: mp3

I need a simple (preferably command line based) tool to extract a segment from some existing mp3 file.

audacity is much too complex for me.

Ideally, I would like a command like

```
extract-mp3-segment --from 1:20 --to 2:40 --output myoutput.mp3 frominput.mp3
```

where `1:20`  is the start time 1 minute 20 seconds

where `2:40`  is the end time i.e. 2 minutes 40 seconds

where `myoutput.mp3`  is the *resulting* mp3 sound file (to create)

where `frominput.mp3`  is the large original mp3 sound file

This is on some *old* Ubuntu 14.04.5 distribution, x86-64

<sup>(the motivation is to extract small religious songs for a funeral, I managed to download the file (from Youtube) and to convert them to mp3)</sup>

#### addenda

Actually I found and used `cutmp3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using ffmpeg (or avconv):

`ffmpeg -ss 00:01:20 -t 00:01:20 -i /path/to/input.mp3 -acodec copy /path/to/output.mp3`

which -ss determines start point and -t determines duration(rather than end time)

Comment: I had to put `-i /path/to/input.mp3` before `-acodec copy` otherwise I had the error `Unknown decoder 'copy'`. In fact I even put it in front of the other options.

Comment: @LudovicKuty same here, edited. Though I don't know why it don't work that way. I really don't remember if I tested it successfully before writing here.